# Most efficient way to compare two panda data frame and update one dataframe based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframe df1 and df2. df2 consist of "tagname" and "value" column. Dictionary "bucket_dict" holds the data from df2.

```
bucket_dict = dict(zip(df2.tagname,df2.value))
```

In a df1 there are millions of row.3 columns are there "apptag","comments" and "Type" in df1. I want to match between this two dataframes like, if

"dictionary key" from  bucket_dict contains in df1["apptag"] then update the value of df1["comments"] = corresponding dictionary key
and df1["Type"] = corresponding bucket_dict["key name"]
. I used below code:

```
for each_tag in bucket_dict: 
    df1.loc[(df1["apptag"].str.match(each_tag, case = False ,na = False)), "comments"] =  each_tag
    df1.loc[(df1["apptag"].str.match(each_tag, case = False ,na = False)), "Type"] =  bucket_dict[each_tag]
```

Is there any efficient way to do this since it's taking longer time.

Bucketing df from which dictionary has been created:

```
bucketing_df = pd.DataFrame([["pen", "study"], ["pencil", "study"], ["ersr","study"],["rice","grocery"],["wht","grocery"]], columns=['tagname', 'value'])
```

other dataframe:

```
  output_df = pd.DataFrame([["test123-pen", "pen"," "], ["test234-pencil", "pencil"," "], ["test234-rice","rice", " "], columns=['apptag', 'comments','type'])
```

Required output:
[image]

Comment: could you create a sample dataframe to work with?

Comment: I provided sample dataframe and expected output in the question @sammywemmy. Requested you to check the question once again

Comment: you can use this a guide : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: updated once again so that you can directly work with the data @sammywemmy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by calling an apply on your `comments` column along with a `loc` on your `bucketing_df` in this manner -

```
def find_type(a):
    try:
        return (bucketing_df.loc[[x in a for x in bucketing_df['tagname']]])['value'].values[0]
    except:
        return ""

def find_comments(a):
    try:
        return (bucketing_df.loc[[x in a for x in bucketing_df['tagname']]])['tagname'].values[0]
    except:
        return ""


output_df['type'] = output_df['apptag'].apply(lambda a: find_type(a))
output_df['comments'] = output_df['apptag'].apply(lambda a:find_comments(a))
```

Here I had to make them separate functions so it could handle cases where no `tagname` existed in `apptag`

It gives you this as the `output_df` -

```
           apptag comments     type
0     test123-pen      pen    study
1  test234-pencil   pencil    study
2    test234-rice     rice  grocery
```

All this code uses is the existing `bucketing_df` and `output_df` you provided at the end of your question.

Comment: as per the question, I want to update based certain condition(substring match)

Comment: @greenking your question could do with some editing to make it a lot more clear. Is the format of the `apptag` always the same ? (does it always end in "-comment")

Comment: Not at all @Karana. apptag can be anything no proper format at all. if "tagname" from the bucketing dataframe contains in the "apptag" then only update "comments" with dictionary key and type with corresponding dictionary value

Comment: @greenking added an edit with additional functions to account for cases where no `tagname` existed in `apptag`

Comment: Thanks it worked but there is no as such performance improvement.

Comment: @greenking I found an issue. Due to the way its setup any apptags that "pencil" get flagged as "pens" as pen is a substring in pencil

Comment: could please tell me one thing  @Karan like in the function find_type where the below check is happening? If "tagname" value from bucketing df contains in the "apptag" column?  Say for example if "pen" contains "test123-pen" then only call the function to update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207101/discussion-between-karan-shishoo-and-greenking).